# angular5 load external script with params

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to load the next script to my angular app

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{google_key}}&libraries=places&language=DE_de"></script>
```

As I know I can put global js to .angular-cli.json (doesn't work for external scripts) or index.html, but how can I add params (google_key)?

Comment: is your google key changing throughout the lifetime of your app? I think params are good for dynamic content, things that might change often or are unknown before the user renders the frontend. In the case of a google api key, I'd suggest that it might be better to replace such a key during your build process instead of the runtime (for example place it in index.html and replace the key before building the app through a script)

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt it's not dynamic - right. Do you suggest something like gulp/grunt solution?

Comment: are you building through angular-cli? I'm currently doing something similar and I just run a script after angular-cli build that updates my `index.html`. I'm combining the call in an npm job, it could look something like this `ng build && node _yourHtmlUpdateFile_`

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt thanks, that should works, but I'm still looking for something more beautiful, it's default requirement and angular-cli should support it from the box without hacks

Answer (score 1):

A quicker solution for a dynamic script in index.html is reference it by id and setting the src attribute from app.component.ts:

```
googleApi = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=
 ${environment.google_key}&libraries=places&language=DE_de`

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.document.getElementById('theId').setAttribute('src', this.googleApi) 
}
```

But, as suggested in the comments, in this case it's probably a better solution to have it as part of the build process.

Comment: thanks, it would work as well, but I think there should be some solution from the box without hacks